# What are the semantics of `after_commit` for `ActiveJob`s?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking at some code and I see the equivalent of

```rb
SomeJob.perform_after_commit(foo, bar, baz)
```

and

```rb
class SomeJob < ActiveJob::Base
  def perform(foo, bar, baz)
    # does the thing
  end
end
```

My understanding of the `after_commit` callback is that it is relevant for `ActiveRecord`s in order to run some callback after a transaction commits.

What does it mean for an `ActiveJob`? Does it default to executing immediately in the background - a "trivial transaction commit", if you will?

Comment: `perform_after_commit` is almost certainly application code and not framework code or a gem. You're really going to have to find the definition and figure out what the heck the author was doing.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the [actual callbacks available for ActiveJob](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#callbacks) and a job doesn't actually know about the lifecycle callbacks inside a model (where transactions happen) since they are enclosed in the model.

Comment: *sigh* great. I feared as much. Appreciate the confirmation. Feel free to make an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the gem [ar_after_transaction](https://github.com/grosser/ar_after_transaction), to execute code after all database transactions are closed.